# How do you use CSS to make a group of images that flow over the edges of the browser window?

Tags: html, css, image

I'm taking a crack at writing a Javascript-based image gallery.  Right now I have the code set so that I know the images will all be at the same height, but...

How can I arrange my markup and CSS so that all of the images will display on just one line, and when a new one would be outside the width of the browser window, the parts of the image that are 'out of bounds' are simply hidden and don't display on the next line?

I've been experimenting with `overflow`, `float`, and `display` in various ways for the images themselves and their container `div` to no avail.  There must be something simple I'm overlooking here.

Right now the markup looks like:

```
<div id="slider">
    <img src="img1.png" /> 
    <img src="img2.png" /> 
    <img src="img3.png" /> 
</div>
```

How should I style this so it displays on one line, even if the combined width of the images is greater than the width of the browser window?

Thanks.

Comment: Heve you tried a div with: max-width:100%; width:100%;overflow:hidden; ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#slider {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow   : hidden;
    width      : 100%
}
```

Comment: `white-space` property, brilliant.  Thanks a bunch.